# Populate Schema on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have two collections one is users and another is cats. I want cats data under my users collection. But I am not getting.

User.js

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = Schema({
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
username: String,
email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
password: String,
role: String,
cats: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Cat' }]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
exports.default = User;
```

Cat.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var catSchema = Schema({
fname: String,
mname: String,
lname: String,
});
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
exports.default = Cat;
```

O/p

> "_id" : ObjectId("5a446ab43533970b8489e1ac"),
>           "username" : "xyz",
>           "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
>          "password""$2a$10$ogerY6OiCRKy9TjPYERaOugUJeqelBl.yToJ4ZBX3ac2MVZQpsKOu",
>           "role" : "user",
>           "cats" : [ ],
>           "__v" : 0

Expected Output

> "_id" : ObjectId("5a446ab43533970b8489e1ac"),
>           "username" : "xyz",
>           "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
>          "password""$2a$10$ogerY6OiCRKy9TjPYERaOugUJeqelBl.yToJ4ZBX3ac2MVZQpsKOu",
>           "role" : "user",
>            "cats" : [{
>           "_id" : ObjectId("5a44707effc66a234447c36b"),
>           "fname" : "felix",
>           "mname" : "",
>           "lname" : "",
>            } ],
>           "__v" : 0

Answer (score 0):

You might combine them into just one schema like below.
No any reason to create schemas separately unless the array count increases a couple of hundreds continuously..

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  username: String,
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
  password: String,
  role: String,
  cats: [
    { 
      _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      fname: String,
      mname: String,
      lname: String,
    }
  ]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
exports.default = User;
```

Comment: I have 10+ collections and i want them under particular use. I think the above method will make complicate

Comment: I found a gist about it. If you have not seen yet, you might take a look -  https://gist.github.com/troyk/1892652

Answer (score 0):

Fix your schema (should be `cats: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cat' }]` and refer to http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data like this, using `model.find().populate('ref')`

```js
const story = await User.find().populate('Cat');
```

It will return all the users and against each user, an array of respective `Cat`. You already mentioned the `ref` of the `Cat` in the `User model`, so you don't need to do anything extra.